# Java ServerSocket class vs embedding Tomcat

Tags: java, sockets, servlets

I want a java server on a windows machine to serve multiple android clients over wifi.
I have embedded a Tomcat to achieve this, and am writing a servlet. 
But i just found the ServerSocket class. 
**Can't i just use the ServerSocket class instead of the embeddable Tomcat?
Whats the benefit for one over the other?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat is a complete Servlet engine. Therefore you can use it when you have Servlets to use. This includes that Tomcat is capable of talking HTTP.

`ServerSocket` is a class that supplies you only an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream`. Everything else (including any protocol) has to be implemented by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ServerSocket` you need to implement everything by yourself, including the HTTP protocol. With Tomcat, all you need is to write the servlet.

Even if you just want a servlet I still expect Tomcat to be a bad choice. Use Jetty, which was made to be embedded. That way you can make something lightweight without tons of configuration files.